# python remove single quotes and spaces from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im using python3 and i want to make this list to containe only the temp items and removing all the spaces and singel quotes.

```
a = ["', '        'temp1', '        'temp12', '        'temp3', '        'temp4', '        'temp5'    "]
```

I want it to look like this :

```
['temp1','temp12','temp3','temp4','temp5']
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: remove single quotes, split at `','`, strip spaces ? Did you try anything to solve this yourself? If so, and you get an error: [mre] and stracktrace please. If not: why not?  There are bazillions of examples on SO on "how to remove X from string" and "how to split string into list" ....

Comment: How did you get that structure?

Comment: I itred from a the examples in this forum and couldnt solve it,

Comment: If those items in single quotes are meant to be comma separated there seems to be a misplaced single quote in each item? E.g. `'        'temp1'` contains three single quotes instead of two, which does not seem right. Please explain how you got the array in the first place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go about this :

```
result = a[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", '')[1:].split(',')
print(result)
```

---

Output:

```
['temp1', 'temp12', 'temp3', 'temp4', 'temp5']
```

Comment: the `[:1]` slice is used to avoid getting an empty string in the resulting list due to the first `','` (note that the string is `',temp1,temp12,temp3,temp4,temp5'` before the split)

Answer (score 4):

Things like this was explained here billion times, but here you are:

```
import re
pattern = r'(\w+\d+)'
s = "', '        'temp1', '        'temp12', '        'temp3', '        'temp4', '        'temp5'    "
result = re.findall(pattern, s)
```

Result:

```
['temp1', 'temp12', 'temp3', 'temp4', 'temp5']
```

Comment: Your answer is better and consistent than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried splitting the list element over single quote and then traversed through all the elements of the created list (used list comprehension) : fetched only those elements which contain the word 'temp'

```
print ([i for i in a[0].split("'") if 'temp' in i])
```

[image: Jupyter notebook Output]